# my background isn't being fixed

Tags: css, scroll, background

I am using the same template as [this one](http://www.surfplanks.com.au), but their `background` stays fixed while scrolling the site, while mine scrolls.

If you go to both sites you will see what I mean. I googled and tried inspecting element and came up with this which fixes my problem, but my `background` isn't responsive anymore.

```
<style>
.jqbga-web--image {background-attachment: fixed;}
</style>
```

[My site](http://www.vinola-wines.com)

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated,.

Answer (score 0):

You should give background to body tag.
[image]

Comment: I managed to get it to work using the sitebuilders setting menu "EDIT HEAD", but my background is only full width if I browse the site on a 1080p screen. It's cropped when I browse it on a 1280x720 macbook. The surfboard site is full width, so what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below to the div you have applied the Image to..

Change background-image:URL(..) to

background:url("https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=2000x1500:format=jpg/path/s851c6cbbc20d5b79/backgroundarea/i3fbea4494e0dd3c4/version/1464635663/image.jpg")center center fixed;

and also add
background-size:Cover;

Comment: I managed to get it to work using the sitebuilders setting menu "EDIT HEAD", but my background is only full width if I browse the site on a 1080p screen. It's cropped when I browse it on a 1280x720 macbook. The surfboard site is full width, so what did I miss?